# Не вводятся символы в EditText

Tags: java, android, xml

Во фрагменте имеется EditText, куда пользователь должен ввести любое число (формат ввода стоит числовой). Однако почему-то ввод не происходит. Цифры на клавиатуре нажимаются, а символы в EditText не отображаются. В чем проблема?

Вот xml фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CalculatorFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculator_text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_below="@+id/text"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/weight"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/weight"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/height"
        android:inputType="number"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/count"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/height"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/count"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/count"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

А вот код фрагмента:

**UPDATE2:**

```
package asus.example.com.fitnessapp;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class CalculatorFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;
    EditText eWeight, eHeight;
    int nWeight, nHeight;

    public CalculatorFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator, container, false);
        Button button = v.findViewById(R.id.count);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                eWeight = v.findViewById(R.id.weight);
                eHeight = v.findViewById(R.id.height);
                nWeight = Integer.parseInt(eWeight.getText().toString());
                nHeight = Integer.parseInt(eHeight.getText().toString());
                if (nWeight-nHeight<100) {
                    textView.setText("Normal weight");
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вашей разметке у вас есть два текстовых поля, в которые должны вводится только цифры. Но проблема в том что у вас не инициализированы они в вашем фрагменте. То есть что у вас есть на данный момент - вы вводите ваши цифры в поля для ввода, а программа их не видит, они есть только на разметке. Для того чтобы все работало нужно сделать так:

```
EditText eTxt1, eTxt2;
```

дальше нужно найти их по id:

```
eTxt1 = v.findViewById(R.id.weight);
eTxt2= v.findViewById(R.id.height);
```

и дальше нужно из них вытаскивать данные. Для этого нужно ввести две строковые переменные которые будут равны тому что вы ввели в поля:

```
String a = eTxt1.getText().toString();
String b = eTxt2.getText().toString();
```

и дальше вы уже конвертируете введенный текст в число и делаете с ним то что вам нужно. Может быть есть более изящный способ для того чтобы вытаскивать сразу цифры из полей, но я пользуюсь на данный момент этим) Смысл я надеюсь понятен. По логике должно работать, но на данный момент не на чем проверить. Если у кого-то будет лучше решение чем мое я с радостью с ним ознакомлюсь. Надеюсь я вам помог, если будут вопросы - не стесняйтесь и спрашивайте, помогу чем смогу. Удачи :)

### update

вот что у вас должно получится в итоге:

```
public class CalculatorFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;
    Button button;
    EditText eWeight, eHeight;
    int nWeight, nHeight;

    public CalculatorFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calculator, container, false);
        button = v.findViewById(R.id.count);
        eWeight = v.findViewById(R.id.weight);
        eHeight = v.findViewById(R.id.height);
        textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textview); // здесь я так и не понял какой именно вам нужен текствью
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                nWeight = Integer.parseInt(eWeight.getText().toString());
                nHeight = Integer.parseInt(eHeight.getText().toString());
                if (nWeight-nHeight<100) {
                    textView.setText("Normal weight");
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

}
```

Comment: С Вашей логикой согласен, но почему-то все равно не работает. Я в вопрос добавил измененный вариант кода фрагмента

Comment: я вам предлагаю все сделать в функции onCreate() может поможет, поместите туда слушатель нажатий на кнопку. Потому что мне кажется что не обязательно отслеживать нажатие на кнопку по id при том что у вас только одна кнопка

Comment: Ну это я делал на случай, если еще кнопки добавлять буду. Но в целом да, разумно

Comment: Переделал метод onCreateView, добавил его в вопрос. Но все равно не работает

Comment: а где вы объявили вам textView?

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii, обновил ответ

Comment: А, точно, извините, что долго тупил. Все изменил, но все равно не работает. Но что заметил: текст в edit добавляется, но такое ощущение, что белым шрифтом написан. То есть я могу его выделить, скопировать в другой edit, но там его все равно не видно. Может это вообще в эмуляторе какая-то проблема?

Comment: возможно, у вас очень странно все построено если честно)

Comment: да я и сам понимаю. Но что поделать - неопытный еще. А textView и button там для того, чтобы по нажатию кнопки в textView результат отобразить

Comment: да но textView я не вижу чтобы был инициализирован в вашем фрагменте, нужно сделать тоже самое что и с кнопкой

Comment: В смысле?  Я ж ему присваиваю значение в коде. Или имеется в виду по умолчанию проинициализировать пробелом например?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84460/discussion-between-andrew-goroshko-and-sergei-mikhailovskii).